# Synonym request: [backbone] ↔ [backbone.js]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[backbone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backbone) is currently tagged with 9 questions, and [backbone.js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js) is currently tagged with 24 questions.  These two tags are mapped together on Stack Overflow, so I think the same thing should be done here as well.

Comment: I agree with you Jamal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags merged and synonym created.